# How to Read a Pem Cert and Private Key Files and create Bouncy Castle X509Certificate and Bouncy Castle AsymmetricKeyParameter dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, bouncycastle

How does one read an unencrypted PEM certificate and its associated private key into usable C# Bouncy Castle objects? I have not found any simple methods of doing this with Bouncy Castle. Much easier to do with dotnet security's X509Certificate2 (just pass the file as bytes into its constructor), but then it is really cumbersome to convert to a bouncy castle `X509Certificate` and the associated private key to a `AsymmetricKeyParameter`. And with Bouncy castle you have to have knowledge on what type of algorithm is used for the signature. What's the easiest way to get a BouncyCastle Certificate from a Pem that has both private and public parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I came up with. It appears to function correctly. I wish there was annotations for Bouncy Castle - the Cryptic cryptology library.

```
 public static class PemFileReader{

    public static X509Certificate ReadCert(string pathToPemFile)
    {
        X509CertificateParser x509CertificateParser = new X509CertificateParser();
        var cert = x509CertificateParser.ReadCertificate(File.ReadAllBytes(pathToPemFile));

        return cert;

    }

    public static AsymmetricKeyParameter ReadPemPrivateKey(string pathToPemFile)
    {

        StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(pathToPemFile);

        Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemReader pemReader = new Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.IO.Pem.PemReader(streamReader);

        PemObject pemObject = pemReader.ReadPemObject();

        PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfo.GetInstance(pemObject.Content);

        AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKeyBC = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privateKeyInfo);

        return privateKeyBC;


    }
}
```