# How to attach a private key to a certificate using Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, x509, pem

I have two PEM files that I need to load in Bouncy Castle. One file is the certificate, the other file is the private key. Using the code from the answer in this article:

[How to Read a Pem Cert and Private Key Files and create Bouncy Castle X509Certificate and Bouncy Castle AsymmetricKeyParameter dotnet core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331614/how-to-read-a-pem-cert-and-private-key-files-and-create-bouncy-castle-x509certif)

I am able to load the two PEM files into a (BC) X509Certificate with the ReadCert() and a (BC) AsymmetricKeyParameter  with the ReadPrivateKey() function.

I.e. I am looking for how to achieve this existing .NET functionality in Bouncy Castle:

```
var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(publicKeyPath, privateKeyPath);
```

My question is how use Bouncy Castle to add the private key to the X509 certificate so that I end up with a full Bouncy Castle X509 certificate containing both the certificate and the private key?

Someone is going to ask why I can't just use the .NET line above. It's slow and buggy on Windows at least. Running 10,000 of those lines kicks my 3080 GPU to 20% and eats two full CPU cores and takes a full minute to run. I'm pretty certain that if I can load the certificate in BC and later convert it to the Windows variant, then I'll bypass the buggy code that eats my system resources.

Comment: Certificates don't contain private keys. As far as I know only Microsoft thought it was a good idea to engineer a class that handles both certificates and private keys and name it "X509Certificate2".

Comment: Hmmm.... Well that would explain the absence of any examples or methods on the  BC x509 object. I have another question on importing pkcs#12 into BC. Any idea if that's possible, and would it then be imported into two objects?